# Why sloped edge labels position is independent from edge direction?

Tags: positioning, labels, edge

For example, that for positioning of edge labels is controlled by `auto=right` option. Than the position of edge labels should be on right side of edges regarding on their direction. However, in the cases when labels are aligned with edges' slopes, than their positions become independent on edges direction:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,  % <---
                        node distance=20mm and 20mm]
\coordinate[label=below:$A$]                (a);
\coordinate[above right=of a, label=$B$]    (b);
\coordinate[right=of a, label=below:$C$]    (c);
\coordinate[above right=of c, label=$D$]    (d);
%
\draw[->]   (a) to["$ab$"] (b) (c) to["$cd$",sloped] (d);
%\draw[->]   (b) to["$ba$"] (a) (d) to["$dc$",sloped] (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and at opposite direction:

[image]

I expected that in the second case all labels will be on the same side of edges, but they aren't. Does meaning of `auto=right` for sloped labels are changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ti*k*Z intelligently (or semi-intelligently ;-) interprets `right`. If you do not want Ti*k*Z to do that, you need to add the `allow upside down` key. Then the label will be always on the right side of the path, but may be upside-down.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,  % <---
                        node distance=20mm and 20mm,allow upside down]
\coordinate[label=below:$A$]                (a);
\coordinate[above right=of a, label=$B$]    (b);
\coordinate[right=of a, label=below:$C$]    (c);
\coordinate[above right=of c, label=$D$]    (d);
%
\draw[->]   (a) to["$ab$"] (b) (c) to["$cd$",sloped] (d);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,  % <---
                        node distance=20mm and 20mm,allow upside down]
\coordinate[label=below:$A$]                (a);
\coordinate[above right=of a, label=$B$]    (b);
\coordinate[right=of a, label=below:$C$]    (c);
\coordinate[above right=of c, label=$D$]    (d);
%
\draw[->]   (b) to["$ba$"] (a) (d) to["$dc$",sloped] (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if you do not `allow upside down`, Ti*k*Z will rotate the label by 180 degrees where appropriate, and then the roles of left and right, and of above and below, get swapped.

**ADDENDUM**: Some first steps towards an automatic solution. The `allow upside down` key, or, more precisely, the `\ifpgfallowupsidedownattime` if, gets really used in `\pgftransformlineattime` and `\pgftransformcurveattime`. One can actually modify these macros to give you something like an automatic solution. **THESE ARE ONLY THE FIRST STEPS** and I really only look at `\pgftransformlineattime` (but the changes for `\pgftransformcurveattime` are analogous). This code now checks if Ti*k*Z adds the additional rotation of 180 degrees, and if so, it changes the anchors such that the node position gets swapped. (In principle the swap code should also work, but it doesn't, perhaps because it gets executed too late.) Here are codes and results:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\newif\iftikzrotateback
\newif\iftikzneedtorotateback
\tikzneedtorotatebackfalse
\tikzset{rotate back/.is if=tikzrotateback,
auto rotate nodes/.style={rotate back=true}}
\makeatletter
\def\pgftransformlineattime#1#2#3{%
  \pgf@process{#2}%
  \pgf@xb=\pgf@x% xb/yb = start point
  \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
  \pgf@process{#3}%
  \pgf@xc=\pgf@x% xc/yc = end point
  \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointlineattime{#1}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}}%
  \ifpgfresetnontranslationattime%
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations%
  \fi%
  \global\tikzneedtorotatebackfalse
  \ifpgfslopedattime%
    \advance\pgf@xc by-\pgf@xb%
    \advance\pgf@yc by-\pgf@yb%
    \ifpgfallowupsidedownattime%
    \else%
      \ifdim\pgf@xc<0pt%
        \iftikzrotateback%   
         \global\tikzneedtorotatebacktrue%
        \fi%
        \pgf@xc=-\pgf@xc%
        \pgf@yc=-\pgf@yc%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xc%
    \pgf@y=\pgf@yc%
    \iftikzneedtorotateback%
% this is the swap code but at the moment I cannot make it work
%      \def\tikz@temp{left}%
%    \ifx\tikz@auto@anchor@direction\tikz@temp%
%      \def\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{right}%
%    \else%
%      \def\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{left}%
%    \fi%
     \def\mynorth{north}%
     \ifx\tikz@anchor\mynorth%
      \edef\my@tikz@anchor{south}%
     \fi%
     \def\mysouth{south}%
     \ifx\tikz@anchor\mysouth%
      \edef\my@tikz@anchor{north}%
     \fi% and so on and so forth, maybe there is already a function that s
     \edef\tikz@anchor{\my@tikz@anchor}%
    \fi% swaps the anchors in TikZ
    \pgfpointnormalised{}% x/y = normalised vector
    \pgf@ya=-\pgf@y%
    \pgftransformcm%
     {\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@y}}%
     {\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}{\pgfpointorigin}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,  % <---
                        node distance=20mm and 20mm,auto rotate nodes]
\coordinate[label=below:$A$]                (a);
\coordinate[above right=of a, label=$B$]    (b);
\coordinate[right=of a, label=below:$C$]    (c);
\coordinate[above right=of c, label=$D$]    (d);
%
\draw[->]   (a) to["$ab$"] (b) (c) to["$cd$",sloped] (d);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,  % <---
                        node distance=20mm and 20mm,auto rotate nodes]
\coordinate[label=below:$A$]                (a);
\coordinate[above right=of a, label=$B$]    (b);
\coordinate[right=of a, label=below:$C$]    (c);
\coordinate[above right=of c, label=$D$]    (d);
%
\draw[->]   (b) to["$ba$"] (a) (d) to["$dc$",sloped] (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for for pointing me to `allow upside down`. Now I see that now is better stick with "not-automatic" solution and such a cases and rather add `swap` option. Maybe will be one day defined `allow upside down swap` function which will do my  manually for now :-). For accepting answer I will wait a while.

Comment: @Zarko It is somewhat nontrivial to make a fully automatic solution work. The `allow up side down` key is really used in `pgfcoretransformations.code.tex` but there it just adds a rotation by 180 degrees if the end point is left of the start point. At this point, Ti*k*Z does not know how far the node/label is away from the line, otherwise one could just shift the node to the other side. That means that if you want a fully automatic solution you will need to modify commands beyond just `\pgftransformlineattime` and `\pgftransformcurveattime`. This is quite some effort, and may break things.

Comment: I imagine, that this is not trivial. In case this was easy, it would have already been done :-). Thank you again for explanation.

Comment: @Zarko I was wrong, one actually *can* make it work, at least in simple examples. I added a "proof of principle". A real solution would IMHO only make sense if the developers of Ti*k*Z are interested in it, and agree to add it once it is sufficiently stable.

Comment: Thank you. A weather prognoses here is that this Sunday is the last sonny ... I will be back latter afternoon and test your last proposal.

Comment: Note to myself: maybe `tikz@label@post` is the point at which one has to hook in? @Zarko In California it is the same: this Sunday is the last sunny day before Monday. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately your addendum doesn't work. Result is the same as in MWE in my question.

Comment: @Zarko On my machine it does. I am compiling on an updated TeXLive 2019 distribution with pdflatex. Are you sure you copied the full thing?

Comment: hm, now works! I not understand, why it didn't at the first test. Now we only need to find a way, how this your nice workaround find a way to `tikz`, presumably to `quotes` library. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zarko One can make a feature request at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf. The problem is that one has to add a lot of cases. The cleanest solution would be to make use of the swap code, but I was not able to get this work because (it seems to me) `\pgftransformlineattime` gets executed too late. But if you make a feature request, more people will look at it, maybe someone has an idea for how to add this in a minimal invasive way.